# Parsing XML with Jsoup

Tags: java, xml, jsoup

I get the following XML which represents a news article:

```
<content>
   Some text blalalala
   <h2>Small subtitle</h2>
   Some more text blbla
   <ul class="list">
      <li>List item 1</li>
      <li>List item 2</li>
   </ul>
   <br />
   Even more freakin text
</content>
```

I know the format isn't ideal but for now I have to take it.

The Article should look like:

- Some text blalalala
- Small subtitle
- List with items
- Even more freakin text

I parse this XML with Jsoup. I can get the text within the `<content>` tag with `doc.ownText()` but then I have no idea where the other stuff (subtitle) is placed, I get only one big `String`.

Would it be better to use an event based parser for this (I hate them :() or is there a possibility to do something like `doc.getTextUntilTagAppears("tagName")`?

Edit: For clarification, I know hot to get the elements under `<content>`, my problem is with getting the text within `<content>`, broken up every time when its interrupted by an element.

I learned that I can get all the text within content with `.textNodes()`, works great, but then again I don't know where which text node belongs in my article (one at the top before h2, the other one at the bottom).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake I made was going through the XML by `Elements`, which do not include `TextNodes`. When I go through it Node by Node, I can check wether the `Node` is an `Element` or a `TextNode`, that way I can treat them accordingly.

Comment: Good that it's working for you now. Now that you've found the solution, please update the question and answer accordingly. And accept your own answer when it is eligible.

Answer (score 9):

Jsoup has a fantastic selector based syntax. [See here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

If you want the subtitle

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("path-to-your-xml"); // get the document node
```

You know that subtitle is in the `h2` element

```
Element subtitle = doc.select("h2").first();  // first h2 element that appears
```

And if you like to have the list:

```
Elements listItems = doc.select("ul.list > li");
for(Element item: listItems)
    System.out.println(item.text());  // print list's items one after another
```

Comment: Who ever graciously did the -1 may please explain the reason so I can improve myself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your effort, but I know how to get the elements. I'll try to specify my question.